# Project template in Visual Studio 2010 and VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix, project-template

I created solution with two projects: WinForms and a web service. I created web reference from WinForms to the web service. Now I want to create a multi-project template with [vsix](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-template-using-vsix-in-visual-studio).

I used this tool and when I want to create new project from this template, VS shows me problem, that it can't find 2 files from 4 in the **web reference** folder. It can't find the `disco` and `wsdl` files.

It is strange because when I create project template manually using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.EXPORTTEMPLATEWIZARD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true) and paste zipped file to VS project templates everything works fine.

**EDIT**

When I create 1 project template with WinForms and web reference everything works. Later I create another template with web service and also works, but together doesn't work.